# Spring Boot: How to setup test data with liquibase in unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm trying to setup the database schema and some test data with liquibase for some tests. Each test has a separate changelog which setup the schema and some specific data for the test.

In order to make my tests working, I need to drop the schema before each test and fill it with new test data. However, it seems that this is not working because some tests are failing because the old test data is still available. I think something with my configuration is not correct. How can I force liquibase to drop the schema before each test?

My tests look as following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyTestConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "liquibase.change-log=classpath:changelog/schema-with-testdata.xml")
public class MyRepositoryTest {
```

The config for the tests looks as follows:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.mypackage")
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.mypackage.domain" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.mypackage.domain", "com.mypackage.infra.persistence" })
public class MyTestConfig {
```

And the application.properties under src/main/test/resources is

```
liquibase.drop-first=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Comment: I had the same problem and posted my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210247/how-to-drop-in-memory-h2db-between-spring-integration-tests/40805764#40805764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7 years later I'm maybe a bit smarter to answer my own question. Spring uses a test context cache between tests. That is, if the spring context remains the same between tests, the context is restored from the cache. This is for speeding up the tests. If you change the data, Spring doesn't notice and restores the context from the cache, even though the requirements have changed. There are several ways to fix this:

- use @DirtiesContext
- use @Transactional on the test
- delete and setup all data "manually" in @BeforeEach

Answer (score 7):

There is a `spring.liquibase.dropFirst` config property. Maybe this is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this completely answers your question. There is another property liquibase.default-schema=schemaNameToCreate

But even with that I was never able to get it to create the schema from scratch.